# Remove the latest URL parameter after "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove any text (or parameters) after the latest "/" in the URL and for that I did this:

```
var current_url = $(location).attr('href');
var clean_url = current_url.substring(current_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

But it's not working because I get any text (or parameters) after the latest "/" and I don't want that. How? What's wrong in my code?

Comment: `location` is a normal object; no need for jQuery.  Use `location.href`.

Comment: What does the url look like?

Comment: Read the documentation for `substring()`; your question shows no research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substring` returns a string starting at the index specified by the first parameter, and going until the index specified by the second parameter, or the end if there isn't a second parameter. So try something like this:

```
var current_url = location.href;
var clean_url = current_url.substring(0, current_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @jason-p it works also I'll read better the docs as SLaks suggest before

Comment: see I have this URL: `http://devserver/app_dev.php/product/new#` and I need to remove this `product/new#` I read docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) but still don't know which of them to use, could you help me?

Comment: I believe you're using the correct function, your logic is just off. You want to remove everything after the .php, right? So maybe you need to change your code to `.substring(0, current_url.indexOf('.php') + '.php'.length)`

Answer (score -2):

Your `clean_url` takes the substring starting at the last index of `'/'`. You need to add a first parameter of `0` if you want everything except that bit:

```
var clean_url = current_url.substring(0, current_url.lastIndexOf('/'));
```